# Raising event in clients through web services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I was trying to write a sample chat application using Web Services in .net 2 , but I have no idea how can I inform the clients whenever a new message comes to the chat server.

the Web Service should send the received message to all clients, but I have no idea how I can send the message to all clients. Does anyone can tell me how to do that in simple way?
Thanks for your help;

Comment: Natively Web Services in .Net 2 requires polling the service, only really WCF supports Duplex calls, and over Http these can be resource intensive.

Comment: What type of client do you have, is it web based or is it a thick client Win Forms app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)

> SignalR is a Async signaling library for .NET to help build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications

A good example that using SignalR for realtime chat is [JabbR](http://jabbr.net) and you can find the source code on [Github](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not common practice for servers to broadcast clients like that. Normally the client should have a little routine to query the server for changes or events.

Comment: It is true that HTTP was not designed with that in mind, but there are still [various ways to mimic server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).